# Identity about integral of logarithm

Tags: integration, logarithms, improper-integrals

Let $\alpha\in(0,1).$

I would like to prove that $$\int_{0}^{\alpha}dx\frac{x}{\log(x)}=\int_{0}^{\alpha^2}dx \frac{1}{\log(x)}.$$

I tried using a change of variables $x\to x^{2}$, integration by parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need integration by parts, indeed by $x^2=t \implies 2xdx=dt$ we have

$$\int_{0}^{\alpha}\frac{x}{\log(x)}dx=\int_{0}^{\alpha^2}\frac12\frac{1}{\log(\sqrt t)}dt$$

then recall that $\log A^n=n\log A$.

Comment: Oh! I did the $x\to x^2$ but I forgot to one $x...$ thanks

Comment: Ah ok! That's fine, you are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

For a slightly different approach, suppose we define 
$$f(t) = \int_0^t \frac{x}{\ln(x)} \; dx$$
and
$$g(t) = \int_0^t \frac{1}{\ln(x)} \; dx$$
Then 
$$f'(t) = \frac{t}{\ln(t)}$$
and $$g'(t^2) = \frac{1}{\ln(t^2)} \cdot 2t = \frac{2t}{2 \ln(t)} = \frac{t}{\ln(t)}$$
so $f'(t) = g'(t^2)$, from which we conclude that $f(t)-g(t^2) = C$, a constant.  Since $f(0) = g(0)$, we conclude $C= 0$, hence $f(t) = g(t^2)$.

Comment: Nice alternative!